# How to draw the binary tree for this input: [1,2,2,3,null,null,3,4,null,null,4]?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, computer-science

This is what I have drawn[image]

I am apparently missing something. How to include the value at index 10 of the array?
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: In the last row of your tree, the next four cells are not used, because they have null parantes and the last [null, 4] are the children of the last 3 in the row above. The "4" nodes have implicit null children. This should give you a symmetrical tree with (1 2 3 4) along the leftmost and rightmost branches.

Comment: (So, to illustrate, I think your tree looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxSlo.png).)

Comment: You seem to assume the input array is providing the tree elements as if the tree is a *complete* binary tree (like for [binary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Implementation)), so that you could use your multiplication method (`2*i+1`, ...etc). But that is not how the input is structured.

Comment: @trincot Please tell me the procedure to draw the tree for an input array which has the tree elements of a tree that is not a complete binary tree?

Comment: Which is your programming language?

Comment: @trincot Java but I just want to draw on paper so that I can have an understanding of the input and test a few cases.

Comment: OK, posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array encoding is not such that you can assume that a node's children are at the index `i*2+1` and `i*2+2`. That would be true if the encoded tree were a *complete* binary tree, but when it is not, you cannot use this formula.

Instead, you should keep track of the bottom layer of the tree as you build it, only registering *real* nodes (not `null`). Then distribute the next children among the nodes in the (then) bottom layer, etc. This is really a breadth-first traversal method.

This is the procedure:

Create a queue, and create a node for the first value in the input list (if the list is not empty), and enqueue it.

Then repeat for as long as there is more input to process:

- dequeue a node from the queue
- read the next two values from the input, and create nodes for them. If there are not enough values remaining in the input, use `null` instead.
- Attach these two nodes as children to the node that you had taken from the queue
- Those children that were not `null` should be enqueued on the queue.

If you apply this algorithm to the example input [1,2,2,3,null,null,3,4,null,null,4], then we get first the root, which is put on the queue. So just before the loop starts we have:

```
        root: 1        queue = [1]
                       remaining input = [2,2,3,null,null,3,4,null,null,4]
```

I depict here the queue contents with numbers, but they really are node instances.

After the first iteration of the loop, in which we read 2 and 2 from the input, create nodes for them, attach them to the dequeued node, and enqueue those children, we get:

```
        root: 1        queue = [2, 2]
             / \       remaining input = [3,null,null,3,4,null,null,4]
            2   2
```

After iteration #2 (note that no null is enqueued):

```
        root: 1        queue = [2, 3]
             / \       remaining input = [null,3,4,null,null,4]
            2   2
           / *
          3
```

After iteration #3:

```
        root: 1        queue = [3, 3]
             / \       remaining input = [4,null,null,4]
            2   2
           / * * \
          3       3
```

After iteration #5:

```
        root: 1        queue = [3, 4]
             / \       remaining input = [null,4]
            2   2
           / * * \
          3       3
         / *
        4
```

After the final iteration:

```
        root: 1        queue = [4, 4]
             / \       remaining input = []
            2   2
           / * * \
          3       3
         / *     * \
        4           4
```

The queue is not empty, but as there is no more input, those queued nodes represent leaves that need no further processing.